# React: re-fetch data in parent component when child component form submits

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-component, react-state-management

I have a parent component which fetches a list of items, these are passed down through child components, eventually reaching an individual form for each item, where you can update it. Once the form is submitted the items values obviously change, however the parent component doesn't re-render.

I understand why this is happening, however I am stuck on a solution to fix this. How would I make the parent component re-fetch the data whenever one of the forms is submitted? I could update the parent state instead, but it is not a direct child (something like a great grandchild..). Would it be easier to save all this fetched data to Redux and update it there? Not sure what best practices are here!

Parent component (simplified):

```
const ThisMonth = () => {
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    axiosGet('this-month-expenses/').then(res => setExpenses(res.data))
}, [])

return (<ExpenseList expenses={expenses} />)
```

}

The expenses prop gets passed down a few components until it reaches the form (also simplified):

```
const ExpenseForm = ({ expense }) => {
const color = useSelector(state => {return state.user.color})
const [name, setName] = useState(expense.name)
const [category, setCategory] = useState(expense.icon.name)
const [date, setDate] = useState(Date.parse(expense.date))
const [cost, setCost] = useState(expense.cost)
const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)

const submitForm = () => {
    setSubmitting(true)
    axiosPost('expense/', {
        "id": expense.id,
        "name": name,
        "date": date,
        "cost": cost,
        "category": category
    })
    .then((res) => (setSubmitting(!(res.status === 200))))
}

return (
        <form>Form here...</form>
        <Button 
            onClick={() => submitForm()}
            isLoading={submitting}
            w='100%' 
            colorScheme={color} 
            color='white' 
            mt={5}
            type="submit"
        >Update Expense</Button>
)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a function in the parent `fetchData()..` and then give it as a prop to the child. Call it on submit, as a `callback`.

For more details, please add a minimal working example.

Edit;
Do something like this

```
const ExpenseForm = ({ expense, onSubmitCallback }) => {
...

const submitForm = () => {
    setSubmitting(true)
    axiosPost('expense/', {
        "id": expense.id,
        "name": name,
        "date": date,
        "cost": cost,
        "category": category
    })
    .then((res) => onSubmitCallback())
}

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added some code as requested. I suppose this way I would have to just pass this prop through all of the other children?

Comment: See the updated answer - but yes, pass the function down through props and call the function in the child you wish. This will actually call it in the parent, not the child, because its a callback. If you dont want to transport it far far down, look into React Context.